# how can i uninstall windows os without affecting ubuntu?

Tags: windows

I have Windows 7 OS in my PC before installing Ubuntu.I want to uninstall windows OS from my PC due to the hanging problem and i want to keep the Ubuntu. So what procedure should be followed?

Answer (score 0):

First of all run this in terminal:

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install gparted
```

Then search and launch gparted from dash. Select /dev/sda (local HDD) as the disk on upper left. You should see your Windows partition formatted NTFS. right click and select "delete".

Then right click your main Ubuntu partition (likely ext3 or ext4) and select "resize/move" and resize it to cover the space of the new free space created by deleted partition. Finally select "apply all operations".

Answer (score 0):

1. what you do , run ubuntu live disk or flash drive and run ubuntu in live mode in your pc.
2. Open gparted in from terminal by : sudo gparted
3. look for the device that contains Windows OS and delete it.
4. format the partition to ext-4 and save all changes in G-Parted by    clicking the green tick at the top.
5. Come out of ubuntu live mode and boot your pc
6. update your grub by : sudo update-grub